# How to pull the background process to the interface in Windows?

Tags: powershell, background-process

I'm using PowerShell to execute a .exe (installation file) file in a remote computer from my computer, I could see that the process is triggered from my computer and can see the process run in the remote computer but it's running as a background process.

```
$COMPUTERNAME = "XXX"
$san = New-PSSession -ComputerName $COMPUTERNAME -Credential YYY
Invoke-Command -Session $san {
    C:\users\Desktop\zzz.exe
}
```

I can't bring it front to the interface.

Can someone help?

Comment: Are you trying to remotely run zzz.exe as UserA, and then interact with it as UserB? I don't think that's possible.

Comment: No, I'm using both with the same profile UserA, Which have equal rights, and also its a domain account

Comment: Then I don't understand why you are executing the application remotely from ComputerA, when you need to see it on ComputerB. Why not just launch it on ComputerB?

Comment: Its a test part of an automation which I'm working, if it succeeded then I move for the next step

Comment: I sense an [X-Y problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). What are you trying to achieve by bringing the process to the foreground?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is very old. I was looking for the same thing and found this unanswered.

Log into the computer XXX using RDC or local console. 
You can confirm sessions by running: `qwinsta`

Change your script (for testing) to use the same session ID

```
SESSIONID = your session ID
psexec IPADDRESS -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD -i SESSIONID -d "C:\users\Desktop\zzz.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand why do you need this.. but you can, for example, create task scheduler object under credential of user, currently logged on target server. It will bring application GUI on front. You can use something like datetime.now + 1 min as task starting time.

Comment: Hi Andrii, Thanks for your suggestion but I'm expecting the answer for PowerShell, since I'm creating it for a massive installation for all the remote computer which are in needs of specific applications, I could see that the cmd lines triggering the job in the remote computer even in diff profiles but its not executing in the interface , its running in background, I need to do it completely with powershell without interference of psexec & other tools, can you help me with powershell?